# Estimating norm of sum of elements of $W^{-1,p}$ with disjoint supports

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is partitioned into disjoint sets $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ (make all the assumptions on geometry you want). Let $f_1, f_2$ be elements of $W^{-1,p}(\Omega_1)$ and $W^{-1,p}(\Omega_2)$ respectively, compactly supported (positive distance from the boundary) in their respective domains. I want to define $f \in W^{-1,p}(\Omega)$ as a sum of $f_1$ and $f_2$ (which is doable due to the compact support assumption). I'm wondering what's the best estimate on the $W^{-1,p}$ norm of $f$ I can get. Ideally I'd like it to be something like $||f||_{W^{-1,p}(\Omega)}^p \leq ||f_1||_{W^{-1,p}(\Omega_1)}^p + ||f_2||_{W^{-1,p}(\Omega_2)}^p$, but I'm not really sure if it holds - I just thought that that's the best I can possibly hope for, and it's the case if $f_1, f_2$ are represented by compactly supported $L^p$ functions. Would very much appreciate any suggestions for a proof/counterexample, a weaker estimate would be fine too.

Comment: Assuming that $W^{-1,p}$ is the dual of $W^{1,q}$, where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, you have equality if $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are a positive distance apart. So I'd guess you have it for all nice partitions. But that's just a guess.

Comment: I want to define $W^{-1,p}$ as the dual of $W^{1,q}_0$ with the norm on the latter  space given as the $q$ norm of the gradient (that's because I want to have some scaling of norms when I dilate a domain $D$ to $\lambda D$ and rescale the functions/distributions accordingly. That gives me problems with patching these two distributions together, because I can't just test on restrictions of $\phi \in W^{1,q}_0(\Omega)$ to $\Omega_i$ - I need to take some cut-offs to ensure this test function is zero on $\partial \Omega_i$ and that may increase its norm. Do you think the estimate still works?

Comment: I'm afraid things won't work out well then. If the supports are close to the contact surface, the norm difference between a $\phi \in W_0^{1,q}(\Omega)$ that makes $\langle f_1 \oplus f_2, \phi\rangle$ large and an "approximation" of $\phi$ that vanishes on the contact surface can be huge. I have no idea how to control that.

Comment: Hm, thinking of the case $n = 1$ with intervals $(a,b)$ and $[b,c)$, if $f_i$ is evaluation at a point close to $b$, it seems you can't. The closer the points are to $b$, the smaller the norm of $f_i$ becomes. But the norm of $\phi \mapsto \phi(p_1) + \phi(p_2)$ changes hardly at all when $p_1,p_2$ move towards $b$.

Comment: thanks, that settles it I guess, I'll need to look for something else